# Animating fragments transition

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I've implemented a layout like this:

[image]

whit this configuration:

```
Fragment A: weight 1
Fragment B: weight 3
```

Now I want that a third fragment (Fragment C) is added in my layout, as shown in the below image:

[image]

I would that the width of screen is divided in this way:

```
Fragment A: weight 1
Fragment B: weight 2
Fragment C: weight 1
```

So that the Fragment B loses a portion of his width, while the width of Fragment A remains the same.

I want also that this operation is made with an animation. While the fragment B is appearing the fragment C loses portion of his width.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried having a look at the [Android-PanesLibrary](https://github.com/cricklet/Android-PanesLibrary)? It seems like it might be the thing you are looking for:

> the menu and all other fragments appear in dynamically added panes of varying sizes.

there is also [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UA-lAGVXoLU&feature=youtu.be) from his YouTube channel showing it in action.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for layout animations. Check the guide in the Android developer's training guides: http://developer.android.com/training/animation/layout.html

What you need to do is set `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` for the layout (xml or in code). In your case for the ViewGroup that has your fragments (you don't show any code, so I can't give you more details). For more elaborate animations some customization might be necessary.

They also have the AndroidDevelopers YouTube channel where they go a bit deeper. This video will help you: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=55wLsaWpQ4g